# Multiplication operator $M_a:\ell^p\rightarrow \ell^q$

Tags: functional-analysis

> Let $1\leq q<p<\infty$. Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence such that for all $(x_n)\in\ell^p$ we have $(a_n x_n)\in\ell^q$. Show that $(a_n)\in\ell^r$ with $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{r}=\frac{1}{q}$ and $\Vert M_a\Vert=\Vert a\Vert_{\ell^r}$, with $M_a(x_n)=(a_n x_n)\in \ell^q$

I can't show that $(a_n)\in\ell^r$, I just know that

$$\Vert M_a(x_n)\Vert =\left(\sum |a_n x_n|^q\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}\leq\left(\sum |a_n |^r\right)^{\frac{1}{r}}\left(\sum | x_n|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}=\Vert a \Vert_{\ell^r}\Vert x\Vert_{\ell^p}$$

can someone help me show the rest?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we prove the Generalized Holder Inequality.

Generalized Holder Inequality: Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure
space. Let $1\leq r<p<\infty$. Define $q=\frac{pr}{p-r},$ then $q\in(1,\infty)$
and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=\frac{1}{r}.$ For any measurable functions
$f,g:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, we have that $||fg||_{r}\leq||f||_{p}||g||_{q}$.
In particular, if $f\in L^{p}$ and $g\in L^{q}$, then $fg\in L^{r}$.

Proof: $\lambda=\frac{r}{p}$, then $\lambda\in(0,1)$ and $1-\lambda=\frac{r}{q}$.
Recall that $\ln:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a concave function.
Let $x,y>0$ be arbitrary, we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lambda\ln x^{p}+(1-\lambda)\ln y^{q} & \leq & \ln(\lambda x^{p}+(1-\lambda)y^{q})\\
x^{r}y^{r} & \leq & \lambda x^{p}+(1-\lambda)y^{q}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Note that the above inequality continues to hold if $x=0$ or $y=0$.
Now, let $f,g:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be measurable functions. If
$||f||_{p}=0$ or $||g||_{q}=0$, then $f=0$ or $g=0$ ($\mu$-a.e.)
and hence $fg=0$ ($\mu$-a.e.). In this case, we have $||fg||_{r}=0$
and hence $||fg||_{r}\leq||f||_{p}||g||_{q}.$ Suppose that $||f||_{p}\neq0$
and $||g||_{q}\neq0$. If $||f||_{p}=\infty$ or $||g||_{q}=\infty$,
we clearly have $||fg||_{r}\leq||f||_{p}||g||_{q}.$ Consider the
case that $||f||_{p},||g||_{q}\in(0,\infty)$. Define $F=|f|/||f||_{p}$
and $G=|g|/||g||_{q}$. Note that $||F||_{p}=||G||_{q}=1$

For each $t\in X$, we have that
$$
F^{r}(t)G^{r}(t)\leq\lambda F^{p}(t)+(1-\lambda)G^{q}(t).
$$
Integrating both sides with respect to $\mu$ yields
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int F^{r}(t)G^{r}(t)d\mu(t) & \leq & \lambda\int F^{p}(t)d\mu(t)+(1-\lambda)\int G^{q}(t)d\mu(t)\\
 & = & \lambda\cdot1+(1-\lambda)\cdot1\\
 & = & 1.
\end{eqnarray*}
On the other hand,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int F^{r}(t)G^{r}(t)d\mu(t) & = & \frac{1}{||f||_{p}^{r}||g||_{q}^{r}}\int|f|^{r}|g|^{r}d\mu\\
 & = & \frac{||fg||_{r}^{r}}{||f||_{p}^{r}||g||_{q}^{r}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Re-arranging terms, we obtain $||fg||_{r}\leq||f||_{p}||g||_{q}.$

---

We go back to your problem: (Note that the notations are different) Let
$1\leq r<p<\infty$. Define $q=\frac{pr}{p-r}$, then $q\in(1,\infty)$
and $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=\frac{1}{r}$.

(1) Let $a=(a_{n})$ be a sequence such that for any $x=(x_{n})\in l^{p},$
$(a_{n}x_{n})\in l^{r}$. Prove that $a\in l^{q}$.

Solution of (1): For each $n$, define $T_{n}:l^{p}\rightarrow l^{r}$
by $T_{n}x=(a_{1}x_{1},a_{2}x_{2},\ldots,a_{n}x_{n},0,0,\ldots),$
where $x=(x_{n})\in l^p$. Clearly $T_{n}$ is linear. Moreover, by the generalized
Holder inequality, we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
||T_{n}x||_{r} & \leq & \left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_{k}|^{q}\right\} ^{\frac{1}{q}}\left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}|x_{k}|^{p}\right\} ^{\frac{1}{p}}\\
 & \leq & \left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_{k}|^{q}\right\} ^{\frac{1}{q}}\left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|x_{k}|^{p}\right\} ^{\frac{1}{p}}\\
 &  & \left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_{k}|^{q}\right\} ^{\frac{1}{q}}\cdot||x||_{p}.
\end{eqnarray*}
This shows that $T_{n}$ is a bounded linear map. Consider the family
of bounded linear maps $\{T_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Observe that
for each $x\in l^{p}$, $\{T_{n}x\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a bounded
subset of $l^{r}$ (For, let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary, then
$||T_{n}x||_{r}^{r}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_{k}x_{k}|^{r}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|a_{k}x_{k}|^{k}<\infty$
because it is given that $(a_{n}x_{n})\in l^{r}$). By the Uniform
Boundedness Principle, $\sup_{n}||T_{n}||<\infty$.

We go to show that $||T_{n}||=\left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_{k}|^{q}\right\} ^{\frac{1}{q}}$.
From the above discussion, we clearly have $||T_{n}||\leq\left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_{k}|^{q}\right\} ^{\frac{1}{q}}$.
If $\left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_{k}|^{q}\right\} ^{\frac{1}{q}}=0$,
we are done. Suppose that $\left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_{k}|^{q}\right\} ^{\frac{1}{q}}>0$.
Let $x=\eta(|a_{1}|^{\frac{q}{p}},|a_{2}|^{\frac{q}{p}},\ldots,|a_{n}|^{\frac{q}{p}},0,0,\ldots)\in l^{p}$,
where $\eta=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_{k}|^{q}\right)^{-\frac{1}{p}}$,
then $||x||_{p}=1$. Note that

\begin{eqnarray*}
||Tx||_{r}^{r} & = & \eta^{r}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|a_{k}\cdot|a_{k}|^{\frac{q}{p}}\right|^{r}\\
 & = & \eta^{r}\sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_{k}|^{(\frac{p+q}{p})r}\\
 & = & \eta^{r}\sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_{k}|^{q}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, $||T_{n}||\geq||T_{n}x||_{r}\geq\eta\left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_{k}|^{q}\right\} ^{\frac{1}{r}}=\left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_{k}|^{q}\right\} ^{\frac{1}{q}}$.
Now, it follows that
\begin{eqnarray*}
||a||_{q} & = & \left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|a_{k}|^{q}\right\} ^{\frac{1}{q}}\\
 & = & \sup_{n}\left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{n}|a_{k}|^{q}\right\} ^{\frac{1}{q}}\\
 & = & \sup_{n}||T_{n}||\\
 & < & \infty.
\end{eqnarray*}

---

(2) Define $T:l^{p}\rightarrow l^{r}$ by $Tx=(a_{n}x_{n})$, where
$x=(x_{n})\in l^{p}$. Prove that $T$ is a bounded linear map and
$||T||=||a||_{q}$.

Proof: Clearly, $T$ is linear. By the Generalized Holder Inequality, for
any $x\in l^{p}$, we have that $||Tx||_{r}\leq||a||_{q}||x||_{p}.$
This shows that $T$ is bounded and $||T||\leq||a||_{q}$. If $||a||_{q}=0$,
we are done. Suppose that $||a||_{p}\neq0$. Define $x=\eta(|a_{n}|^{\frac{q}{p}})$,
where $\eta=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|a_{k}|^{q}\right)^{-\frac{1}{p}}$.
By direct verification, $||x||_{p}=1$. Therefore, $||T||\geq||Tx||_{r}=\left\{ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|a_{k}|^{q}\right\} ^{\frac{1}{q}}=||a||_{q}$.
This shows that $||T||=||a||_{q}$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Note that $\|M_a\|=\|a\|_{\ell^r}$.

Proof: Set $s=p/q$ and $t=r/q$. Note that $1<s,t$ and that $1/s+1/t=1$. We can apply Holder's inequality:
If $x=(x_k)\in\ell^p$ we have that
$$\|M_ax\|_{\ell^q}^q=\sum_k|a_kx_k|^q\leq\sum_k\bigg(\big(|a_k|^q\big)^t\bigg)^{1/t}\cdot\bigg(\sum_k(|x_k|^q)^s\bigg)^{1/s}$$
But $qt=r$ and $qs=p$ so raising both sides to $1/q$ we get that
$$\|M_ax\|_q\leq\|a\|_r\cdot\|x\|_p$$
and this shows that $\|M_a\|\leq\|a\|_r$. For the other inequality, set $\delta=\frac{r}{q}-2\in\mathbb{R}$ and for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ set
$$x_n=(\bar{a_1}\cdot|a_1|^{\delta},\bar{a_2}\cdot|a_2|^\delta,\dots,\bar{a_n}\cdot|a_n|^\delta,0,0,0,0\dots)\in\ell^p$$

Now $$\|M_a\|=\sup_{x\neq0}\frac{\|M_ax\|_q}{\|x\|_p}\geq\frac{\|M_ax_n\|_q}{\|x_n\|_p}$$

But $\|M_ax_n\|_q=\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|^{(\delta+2)q}\bigg)^{1/q}=\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|^r\bigg)^{1/q}$ and $\|x_n\|_p=\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|^{(\delta+1)p}\bigg)^{1/p}=\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|^r\bigg)^{1/p}$, so
$$\|M_a\|\geq\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|^r\bigg)^{1/r}$$
and this is true for all $n$, so letting $n\to\infty$ yields $\|a\|_r\leq\|M_a\|$.

2. Since $(a_nx_n)\in\ell^q$ for all $(x_n)\in\ell^p$, the linear map $M_a$ acts as $M_a:\ell^p\to\ell^q$. Now $\ell^p$ and $\ell^q$ are Banach spaces, so in order to show that $M_a$ is bounded we can use the closed graph theorem.

Let $(x_n)\subset\ell^p$ be a sequence (of sequences, i.e. $x_n=(x_k^{(n)})_{k=1}^\infty\in\ell^p$ for all $n$) such that $x_n\to0$ in $\ell^p$. We use the closed graph theorem: assuming that $M_ax_n\to y$, where $y\in\ell^q$, we will show that $y=0$.

Proof: Indeed, if $y=(y_k)$, then for any $k$ we have that
$$|y_k-a_kx_k^{(n)}|\leq\|y-M_ax_n\|_q\to0.$$
Therefore $y_k=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_kx_k^{(n)}$. But
$$|x_k^{(n)}|\leq\bigg(\sum_{j}|x_j^{(n)}|^p\bigg)^{1/p}=\|x_n\|_p\to0$$
so $x_k^{(n)}\to0$, and therefore $a_kx_k^{(n)}\to0$, i.e. $y_k=0$. Since this was true for any $k$, $y=0$ as we wanted.

The closed graph theorem now yields that $M_a$ is a bounded operator, so $\|M_a\|<\infty$. Since $\|M_a\|=\|a\|_{\ell^r}$, we conclude that $\|a\|_{\ell^r}<\infty$, i.e. $a\in\ell^r$.